# ERROR:(null) is not a valid containment controller key path?

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, storyboard

I'm trying to present a navigation controller as a modal and I'm getting this warning:

> ERROR:(null) is not a valid containment controller key path

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? I just connected a segue from a button in another navigation controller to the designated navigation controller and it won't work and I get this warning.

Comment: Please tag your question correctly, knowing what software and versions you are using will improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have exactly the same problem, only with a UIBarButtonItem. The button is obviously not null and IB allows me to drag from it to the UIViewController I want to seque to. The problem is not specific to a Modal transition and occurs with Push as well.

Comment: I believe its a bug on Xcode.. I changed back to Interface Builder until a stable version of Story Builder would come.. :( try opening a new project and see if it reoccurring.

Comment: please let me know if you solved it

Comment: Where are you getting this warning, and what do you mean by "it won't work"? The same thing is present in Apple's own templates - for example, build a project from the Utility Application template and you'll see this warning in the storyboard editor on the FlipsideViewController for the segue that references it. It doesn't prevent the example from working, though.

Answer (score 3):

This looks a bug in XCode note the sample "Utility App" displays this warning as well, but functions as expected.

Comment: Xcode is so buggered, you can't connect UITextFields to UIViewControllers if they're in prototype table cells either...!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're passing a value which is actually holding nothing at all, to your navigation controller.  I'd use NSLog to check the contents of the value being passed to the controller, and find out why it's null.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I realized that the view I was anchoring to for my Popover segue was being deleted, therefore, that view was nil.  I fixed that issue and this issue went away.